# final int variable increment not working

Tags: android

I am using following script to link audio file with a text

```
TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
link.setText(buildStringToPlaySound(context, "Play <u>song</u> or <u>poem</u>",new String[] {"http://www.domain.com/song.mp3","http://www.domain.com/poem.mp3"}));
link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

public SpannableStringBuilder buildStringToPlaySound(final Context context, String str, final String[] url)
{
   CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(str);
    SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
    UnderlineSpan[] underlines = strBuilder.getSpans(0,strBuilder.length(),UnderlineSpan.class);
    //--------------------------------------
    int i=0; //line 1
    //--------------------------------------   
    for(UnderlineSpan span : underlines) {
       int start = strBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
       int end = strBuilder.getSpanEnd(span);
       int flags = strBuilder.getSpanFlags(span);
       ClickableSpan myActivityLauncher = new ClickableSpan() {

         public void onClick(View view) {
             try {
                //--------------------------------------
                playAudio(url[i]); //line 2
                //--------------------------------------
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }

       };

       strBuilder.setSpan(myActivityLauncher, start, end, flags);
       //--------------------------------------
       i++; //line 3
       //--------------------------------------
    }

    return strBuilder;
}
```

Problem is, when I use `line 1` as `final int i = 0;`

Line 3 shows an error

`The final local variable i cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment`

But if i use `line 1` as `int i=0;`

Line 2 shows an error

`Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different method`

Comment: you can add variable in the cycle e.g:  final j = i; and use it inside the class cause primitives in Java are immutable and you can't change its value without changing itself.

Comment: Thanks @MargaritaLitkevych I did solve it getting idea from your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting idea from @Margarita Litkevych's comment

Adding a line `final int j=i;` inside for loop and replaceing variable `i` with `j` inside `playAudio(url[j]);` working fine.

```
TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
link.setText(buildStringToPlaySound(context, "Play <u>song</u> or <u>poem</u>",new String[] {"http://www.domain.com/song.mp3","http://www.domain.com/poem.mp3"}));
link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

public SpannableStringBuilder buildStringToPlaySound(final Context context, String str, final String[] url)
{
   CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(str);
    SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
    UnderlineSpan[] underlines = strBuilder.getSpans(0,strBuilder.length(),UnderlineSpan.class);
    //--------------------------------------
    int i=0; //line 1
    //--------------------------------------   
    for(UnderlineSpan span : underlines) {

    //=================================
    final int j=i;   //added this line
    //=================================

       int start = strBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
       int end = strBuilder.getSpanEnd(span);
       int flags = strBuilder.getSpanFlags(span);
       ClickableSpan myActivityLauncher = new ClickableSpan() {

         public void onClick(View view) {
             try {
                //------------------------- //==================
                playAudio(url[j]); //line 2 //Replaced i with j
                //--------------------------//==================
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }

       };

       strBuilder.setSpan(myActivityLauncher, start, end, flags);
       //--------------------------------------
       i++; //line 3
       //--------------------------------------
    }

    return strBuilder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make variable i as your class instance variable (scope will be through out the class) then it will not alert you to make the variable as final. :)

Answer (score 0):

The variables i is the local variables in the buildStringToPlaySound() method.
When the buildStringToPlaySound() method returns, local variables i will be cleaned up from the stack, so they won't exist anymore after buildStringToPlaySound() returns.

So you can initialize the variable in the anonymous class but in your case make the variable to global so it won't be cleaned from stack.